# Text Inside Parantheses with Smarty

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, smarty

I have a text like **.com registration (domain.com)** or **xl hosting (domain.com)**

I want to get only the domain which is inside parantheses with Smarty.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you post some code? Do you need the text in php or in your html template?

Comment: I need the code in HTML. It is normally looks like `{$o.title}` but I need to get only inside parantheses. Maybe somthing like `{$o.title|regex_replace:"/\G[^(]*(\([^)]+\))/":" "}` @Sniffer's regex makes it right on his link but doesn't work with Smarty

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(\([^)]+\))/g
```

**Edit:** In the previous expression the domain or whatever is inside the parentheses is captured in group 1, so you can access what was matched in that group.

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/yS5tH3)

If you need to replace everything except what is inside the parentheses then you can use the following expression:

```
\G[^(]*(\([^)]+\))
```

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/tI4rO9)

Comment: Thx Sniffer. Actually one of the biggest problem is doing this with Smarty. I tried some working examples to integrate myself but didn't work.

Comment: @xy_ Sorry I don't work with Smarty. I saw the [tag:php] tag and this regex works with PHP.

Comment: I find the way as `{$o.title|regex_replace:"/(\([^)]+\))/":" "}` but this clears the parantheses. I need to clear both parantheses and outside. What should be the pattern? I need inside parantheses.

Comment: @xy_ I don't fully understand your request. You want to clear all characters and keep just what is inside the parentheses ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
{$preg = preg_match("/\(([^)]*)\)/", $o.title, $results)}
{$results[1]}
```

Comment: Is this php code or Smarty? Does Smarty has preg_match function? This returns neither an error nor a result for me, unfortunately

Comment: This is php inside a smarty template. Works for me and returns the result in my template. Maybe try putting a `<p>` tag around the result?

Comment: I just pasted the code also with `<p>` outside. What could be wrong?

Comment: perhaps the `$o.title`? Try replacing it by one of the strings in your question. Maybe it's just not finding a match and therefor giving no result.

Comment: I used `{$preg = preg_match("/\(([^)]*)\)/", ".com registration (domain.com)", $results)}`but still nothing

Comment: Strange, it works perfectly for me. You didn't forget `{$results[1]}` right? Maybe try `{var_dump($results)}`

Comment: `var_dump` returns `null`for every row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36873/discussion-between-dark-ashelin-and-xy)